# Catching and Handling concurrency violations on TableAdapter

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ado.net, concurrency, tableadapter

I am using a `TableAdapter` to connect to my database table.

When I perform an `Update` and someone else has updated the same row I get a concurrency violation error. As expected.

So at this point I give the user the option to Save regardless or Cancel changes

If they cancel I can just performs a `Fill` to get an updated copy of the data but what if they want to overwrite? How do I actually force a save of the data overwriting the data held in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a SQLCommandBuilder to generate your update statements then set
CommandBuilder.ConflictOption=ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges;
 and then do the Update() again.

Comment: Then you have to generate your own UpdateCommand to only use the Primary Key column in the Update SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Right click table adapter, click 'Edit queries in Dataset designer'.

In the Data set designer window, select TableAdapter and go to its Properties.

In the properties, expand Update statement, and go into CommandText property. In the update command where condition, remove all the conditions and keep only the primary key column. for example:

```
UPDATE customer
SET column1 = @column1, column2 = @column2
WHERE pk_column = @pk_column
```

Now the concurrency exception wont appear again, since this query will overwrite the data based on the primary key alone.